# Why is the sum of smallest components of a vector a concave function?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

> The sum of the k smallest components of a vector is a concave function

I came across this statement but have been unable to convince myself why it's true. I've been going at it from the definition of concavity:

$f(\theta a + (1 - \theta)b) \ge \theta f(a) + (1-\theta) f(b)$.

Can someone help me find a proof of this? Thanks!

**Update**

Thanks for the feedback - in the equation above, I'm using the following definitions:

- $a, b \in {\rm I\!R}^n$
- $0 \le \theta \le 1$
- $f(x) = \sum_{i}^k x_{[i]}, x \in {\rm I\!R}^n$, where $x_{[i]}$ denotes the *i*th smallest entry of x

Comment: Smallest entries? How many entries are you summing? What is it a function of?

Comment: 1. Please state the actual question in the body of the post. 2. Please properly define your terms.

Comment: What does the sum of smallest entries mean?

Comment: Ah sorry, I was using the term "entries" in place of "components." I've corrected that in my question.

Answer (score 2):

I found what I was looking for in *Boyd and Vandenberghe*, pp. 80, Ex. 3.6 *"Sum of r largest components"*. The sum of a k specific components of a vector is a linear function. For example, the sum of the first two components would be:

$\sum_{i=0}^1 x_i = a^Tx$ where $a^T = \begin{matrix} [1&1&0&0&\ldots & 0]\end{matrix}$

The set of all possible sums of k components is thus a finite set of linear functions. The sum of the largest components is the pointwise supremum of this set. The Pointwise supremum $\sup_k {f_k(x)}$ preserves convexity if $f_k$ is convex for all k, thus the sum of the k largest components of a vector is convex.

To extend this proof for the k smallest components, simply negate the vector.